# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, election-2016

Aviation's [first moderator election](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: voretaq7] [image: casey] [image: Farhan]

They will be replacing [the existing crew](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/moderators-pro-tempore-announcement) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking Lnafziger and egid who (along with votetaq7) did so much to guide this site through the beta stage. Although they are no longer moderators, I have no doubt they will be leaders on the site in less-formal capacity.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5896212649607168/0).

Comment: I'm FREE! I mean, congratulations!

Comment: @egid: http://i.imgur.com/VmmLNQr.jpg

Comment: Congratulations all!!  I will indeed continue to participate, but my main goal (while this site was even still just an Area 51 proposal) was to get the community up and running so that we all have a great resource for help in the aviation field.  I feel that this has been more than accomplished and the knowledgeable people to continue to provide the more general aviation community a great service.

Answer (score 20):

Congratulations guys! Good luck and have fun as our new moderators!

Answer (score 15):

I would like to thank [@Lnafziger](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69/lnafziger), [@egid](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/39/egid) and [@voretaq7](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/voretaq7) for the excellent help and continuous dedication. I have learnt a lot from them and the entire community.

I am looking forward to help the community in this new role. And also to work with [@casey](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/258/casey) (who has excellent knowledge in [Earth Sciences](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/users/64/casey), in addition to aviation) and [@voretaq7](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/users/64/voretaq7) (who's win confirms that [not being nice](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28602992#28602992) always pays off).